# how to make my slideshow loop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

after the last slide my slide show  inverts the slides order to begin from the first slide i want it to loop .. i dont know what to change in this code and im a beginner . i'll be very thankful if anybody answered ...

```
//direction settings
    if(opts.direction == 'right'){
        cur = maxi; //starting from last slide
        autoMove = opts.prev; //changing the auto-scroll direction
    $(opts.slides).children().each(function(e){ //inverting the slide order
            if(e = 0){
                var child = $(this).detach();
                $(opts.slides).prepend(child);
            }
    });
    }
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could share some more information about the problem like the markup and css etc.